# What is strong homomorphism?

Tags: logic

On pg. 26 of Mathematical Logic notes of Lou van den Dries, there is a definition, however as a beginner I do not understand the difference between $homomorphism$ and $strong$ $homomorphism$. Could you give me specific examples for both so that I can grasp the definition? (I do not understand [Two definitions of strong homomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466657/two-definitions-of-strong-homomorphism), too.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A homomorphism preserves relations: if a relation holds in the "source," it also holds in the "target." A strong homomorphisms preserves relations *and failures of relations*: if a relation *fails* in the source, it also has to fail in the target!

For example, let $G$ be a graph on two vertices $a$ and $b$, with no edges; and let $H$ be a graph on two vertices $c$ and $d$, with an edge from $c$ to $d$. *(Formally: our language has a single binary relation symbol $R$. $G$ has universe $\{a, b\}$, and $R^G=\emptyset$; and $H$ has universe $\{c, d\}$, and $R^H=\{(c, d)\}$.)* Then the map $a\mapsto c, b\mapsto d$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$, but not a strong homomorphism.

Comment: Note that we only see the distinction between homomorphism and strong homomorphism at the level of *relations*: if our language only has function/constant symbols (e.g. groups, rings, fields, . . .), then homomorphisms and strong homomorphisms are the same thing.

Comment: To be precise, in your example you are talking about _directed_ graphs.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey Does it have to be directed? I mean, can it be still an example if the graph is not directed? I want to say, yes.

Comment: @Serpenche: Sure, if you let $R(x,y)$ be a binary relation that says "there is an edge between $x$ and $y$".  You would just have $R^H=\{(c,d),(d,c)\}$ instead then, since the edge goes both ways.